# How Mathematica handles Heaviside functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

I have a question on how mathematica computes this simple example. I can't reproduce this result on paper:

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x - s]*HeavisideTheta[x - (1 - z)], {x, 0, 1},Assumptions -> {0 < s < 1}]
```

Output:

```
HeavisideTheta[z] (z - (-1 + s + z) HeavisideTheta[-1 + s + z])
```

Comment: How about assumptions on `z`?

Comment: How about not, bb

Answer (score 1):

Test it graphically.

```
fH[x_, s_, z_] = HeavisideTheta[x - s]*HeavisideTheta[x - (1 - z)];

intfH[s_, z_] = Integrate[fH[x, s, z], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {0 < s < 1}];

SetOptions[Manipulator, Appearance -> "Labeled"]; Manipulate[
Plot[{fH[x, s, z], intfH[s, z]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {s, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 3}]
```

[image]